# PHP/MySQL - Page/Sort loads slowly

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quick question, might be simple, maybe not.  I'm not versed in PHP, HTML, or MySQL, but I am taking a shot at it.  Here is the sample page I'm working with: http://www.djdarby.com/sorter.php.  I'm displaying a table of 19600 containing two fields, artist and song.  The problem is that it loads extremely slow, and I have no idea where to point the finger.  Maybe my query is too simple, or I am loading too much at one time.  Here is the code, since the PHP turns invisible on page source. Is there a quicker way to output this data?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I'm using javascript to make the table, [TinyTable](http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/table-sorter/) to be exact.

**EDIT NUMERO DOS:**  I made sorter2.php and it seems to load much quicker, so is this a javascript issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
        $con = mysql_connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", "xxxx", "xxx");
       // if (!$con) {
       //         die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
       // } else {
       //         echo "\r\nConnected to the database.";
       // }
        $db = mysql_select_db("djdarby", $con);
       // if (!$db) {
       //         die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
       // } else {
       //         echo "\r\nSelected to the database.";
       // }
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TinyTable</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="sortable">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th><h3>Artist</h3></th>
                                <th><h3>Song</h3></th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <?php
                          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from SONGLIST", $con);
                          //if (!$result) {
                          //  die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
                          //} else {
                          //  echo "\r\nSelected the table SONGLIST in database djdarby.<br /><br />";
                          //}

                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ARTIST'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['SONG'] . "</td></tr>";
                          }
                        ?>
                </tbody>
  </table>
        <div id="controls">
                <div id="perpage">
                        <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                                <option value="250">250</option>
                        </select>
                        <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                </div>
                <div id="navigation">
                        <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                        <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                        <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                        <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
                </div>
                <div id="text">Displaying Page <span id="currentpage"></span> of <span id="pagelimit"></span></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
  var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter("sorter");
        sorter.head = "head";
        sorter.asc = "asc";
        sorter.desc = "desc";
        sorter.even = "evenrow";
        sorter.odd = "oddrow";
        sorter.evensel = "evenselected";
        sorter.oddsel = "oddselected";
        sorter.paginate = true;
        sorter.currentid = "currentpage";
        sorter.limitid = "pagelimit";
        sorter.init("table",1);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: My guess is the JS is what is slowing down your page load, as it is going to have to iterate over 19600 tr elements.  If you remove the JS code and load the page without it, does that help?

Comment: Limit your query to only what is applicable to the current page.

Comment: I think Kyle is right you should remove all java-scripts from your page and see. If it runs fast, then I would suggest to try a different plugin like table from `datatables.net`

Comment: Kyle and Sami, I made a sorter2.php page without the javascript and it is loads faster, will try something from what you provided, thanks. And ethrbunny, what would you recommend? Adding a id column to my MySQL table, and using query strings to load a bit at a time?

Comment: Sami, tried that datatable jscript, and unfortunately same issue.  It gets the data from the MySQL server with amazing speed, but I think it is getting tripped up trying to print 19600 x 2 <td>s and 19600 <tr>s.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Append "LIMIT $start,$stop" to the query string and try not to use too many records in one page

Comment: Can you provide more details on how he can accomplish this? As is, this provides no value more than ethrbunny's comment already has offered.

Comment: This answer seems applicable for sure, I've considered querying only 10-25 at a time, and I understand the syntax behind using LIMIT, but how would this work with pagination?  I want the user to easily click the next page button. The only way I could think to do this would be HTTP query strings in the url to tell me how many ids to display, but then I still wouldn't know how to set that up with sorting and whatnot, and at the same time allowing for searches.  Care to elaborate?